# getting unsupported media type error by running docker pull from ghcr.io ( image made automaticly by github action )

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, ghcr

i'm using github action to automaticly build docker image of my project it is published in my github packages

when i use command below

`docker pull ghcr.io/...`

i get this error

`unsupported media type application/vnd.dev.cosign.simplesigning.v1+json`

i'm already using github token to pull my image . so i dont get any `unauthorized` error

this is the auto generated yaml file by github action

```
name: DockerImage

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '24 17 * * *'
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
    # Publish semver tags as releases.
    tags: [ 'v*.*.*' ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

env:
  # Use docker.io for Docker Hub if empty
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  # github.repository as <account>/<repo>
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
      # This is used to complete the identity challenge
      # with sigstore/fulcio when running outside of PRs.
      id-token: write
      

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Install the cosign tool except on PR
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign-installer
      - name: Install cosign
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: sigstore/cosign-installer@6e04d228eb30da1757ee4e1dd75a0ec73a653e06 #v3.1.1
        with:
          cosign-release: 'v2.1.1'

      # Workaround: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/461
      - name: Setup Docker buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@79abd3f86f79a9d68a23c75a09a9a85889262adf

      # Login against a Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@28218f9b04b4f3f62068d7b6ce6ca5b26e35336c
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ac9327eae2b366085ac7f6a2d02df8aa8ead720a
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max


      # Sign the resulting Docker image digest except on PRs.
      # This will only write to the public Rekor transparency log when the Docker
      # repository is public to avoid leaking data.  If you would like to publish
      # transparency data even for private images, pass --force to cosign below.
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign
      - name: Sign the published Docker image
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        env:
          # https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-an-intermediate-environment-variable
          TAGS: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          DIGEST: ${{ steps.build-and-push.outputs.digest }}
        # This step uses the identity token to provision an ephemeral certificate
        # against the sigstore community Fulcio instance.
        run: echo "${TAGS}" | xargs -I {} cosign sign --yes {}@${DIGEST}
```

i search about error and some said to update my docker version
but i'm alredy using the latest version of docker `Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996`

so i reinstalled docker but i steal have the same problem

Comment: same issue. any luck?

Comment: @akrv i just answered this question

Answer (score 2):

change `docker pull ghcr.io/azita-abdollahi/pdf2word:sha256-dbe0311d583aab18bad36ed0ba3c920ca57fa4779b1404d5706b1e0837f5adce.sig` to `docker pull ghcr.io/azita-abdollahi/pdf2word:master`  It worked for me!
[image: Examples Package]

Answer (score 1):

i was using the wrong image.
when i click on my app image in github packages list
i see the page below
i was using the number 1 in the image because it said 'Install from the command line' on above of the box

then i tried master tag i arrowed in image and it worked
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35117634)